Word update (2410) crashing Word when setting HeaderFooter.LinkToPrevious to False
The latest Word update (version 2410 build 16.0.18129.201000 64-bit) is crashing Word for us. We believe its occurring when we set the HeaderFooter.LinkToPrevious property to False for an even page header. This is done as part of a much larger process of compiling a new document from multiple other documents. Rolling back Word and the error disappears. We have one machine it consistently occurs on, another that occurs only once in three occurrences, and a 32 bit machine with zero occurrences. This is a command we've had issues with in the past and wrapped it in exception handlers and retry loops, but on this occasion it appears to crash Word immediately as our tracing elsewhere is not being hit. Our app is a VB.Net COM add-in. Anyone else got more info to add? We're hoping it will be fixed in next update. Cheers Tim.

Have you been able to strip your VBA code down to a bare minimum as a test to create a footer, then create the next footer and link to previous to see if the error occurs in a tightly controlled environment?  I'm not saying it's your "other" code necessarily, but having that isolated test set (posted here) would help us all track down the real issue.

You might be interested in: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/43339-combine-multiple-word-documents.html
